# Angular4 doesn't load npm installed Firebase

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, npm, http-status-code-404

I am attempting to use npm installed Firebase with my Angular4 app. I have npm installed the latest version of Firebase (version 4.1.1) and checked it has installed correctly. I have input the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { initializeApp, database } from 'firebase';


@Component({
  selector: 'dInstruct-app',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
      <a routerLink="/calendar">Calendar</a>
      <a routerLink="/customers">Customers</a>
      <a routerLink="/accounts">Accounts</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'dInstruct';

  config = {
    apiKey: ...
    authDomain: ...
    databaseURL: ...
    projectId: ...
    storageBucket: ...
    messagingSenderId: ...
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {
    initializeApp(this.config);
    database().ref().on('value', (snapshot: any) => console.log(snapshot.val()));
  }
}
```

However, when I attempt to load the app with the above Firebase code in place, it fails with errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:28 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/firebase
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/firebase
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1055:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:38)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/firebase as "firebase" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1055:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:38)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/firebase as "firebase" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js
(anonymous) @ localhost/:28
```

What problem is occuring here?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Comment: I'll give it a go... hmmm, same error. Thanks for giving it a shot, though.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, after checking on the Angular Glitter, the issue is with using the Angular Quickstart to create the app, rather than angular-cli. I created a new app in the cli and it's now working fine with the npm version of Firebase, without error.

Just a heads-up but I would suggest being wary about using the Angular Quickstart for any production apps, even small scale ones.

That was the solution anyway. Now, all I have to do is port all of the custom code from the old app into the new one...

Alternatively, the following solution is also available if you can't or don't want to move to a cli generated app:

> You need to tell SystemJS where to find firebase. E.g. adding an entry
>   to the SystemJS config's map property.